# Rotate second monitor with nvidia

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

I have two monitors the left/primary is aligned horizontally but the right/secondary is aligned vertically.  When I first installed, I set this up without problem using the display settings.  But when I installed the nvidia driver, I can no longer rotate the second monitor.  I looked into the nvidia x server settings but I don't see any option to rotate the display and when I look at the display settings, it only sees one large "Unknown" monitor.

OS: Linux-X86_64 (Ubuntu 11.10)

GPU: Nvidia NVS 290

Nvidia drivers: version: current

Comment: In your NVIDIA X Server Settings, do you have the item "X Server Display Configuration"? Is this where you see just one large "unknown" monitor? Does the "Detect Displays" button make any difference?

Comment: @Joe  In the NVIDIA X Server Settings I see both monitors.  The configuration is set to Twinview.  But when I look under "System Settings" - "Display" all I see is one large "unknown" monitor.  In the original install, I could see both monitors on this screen which I could rotate however I wanted.

So I guess I'm asking if its possible through the NVIDIA interface to rotate a display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rotate just one monitor with Ubuntu/Nvidia](http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2009/08/rotate-just-one-monitor-with.html) worked for me on Ubuntu 10.10; YMMV. Please note that [Xinerama conflicts with Compiz](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/compiz-startet-nicht-mehr/#post-3852317) - I no longer get desktop effects. Posted a [separate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97074/how-to-rotate-one-monitor-and-keep-compiz) about this issue.