# How to rotate one monitor and keep Compiz?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, rotate-monitor

I was able to [rotate one out of two monitors](http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2009/08/rotate-just-one-monitor-with.html) while using the latest nVidia driver (290.10 for Linux-x86_64), but the guide calls for using Xinerama which according to some is [not compatible with Compiz](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/compiz-startet-nicht-mehr/#post-3852317). True enough, after restarting the rotation works (even in the login screen), but I can't start `compiz` anymore:

```
$ compiz --replace --display :0.0 --sm-disable &
compiz (core) - Fatal: No composite extension
Launching fallback window manager
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".
```

Is there any way to have all of the following:

- Compiz effects
- One rotated monitor
- Drag windows between monitors

Comment: For my AMD display card, I have the option in the "System Settings",  "Displays" to choose Resolution and Rotation for each individual monitor using the default display driver with Compiz (no Xinerama).  Do you not have this ability?  Or do you lose it when using the proprietary driver?  I personally don't install the proprietary drivers because for my use, there is no discernible difference.  But I don't play games, except simple 2D ones like Freecell.  I have always found the proprietary drivers to be a constant source of amusement, not the good kind. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try xrandr. There is my rotate script for EeePC with external monitor

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage:
# ./rotate VGA1 right
s=${1:-'LVDS1'}
r=${2:-'left'}
echo $s;

# see `xrandr` for output modes for all screens
case $s in
'LVDS1')
  m='1024x600' #default resolution of EeePC 1005ha
;;
'VGA1')
  m='1024x768' #best resolution for LG FLATRON 795FT Plus which plugged to EeePC
;;
esac

case `xrandr | grep $s | sed 's/^\(.*\+0 \)\(.*\) (.*/\2/g'` in
'left')
  echo 'returning from left to the normal state on screen '$s' with the '$m' mode'
  xrandr --output $s --mode $m --rotate normal
;;
'right')
  echo 'returning from right to the normal state on screen '$s' with the '$m' mode'
  xrandr --output $s --mode $m --rotate normal
;;
*)
  echo 'rotating to the '$r' on screen '$s' with the '$m' mode'
  xrandr --output $s --mode $m --rotate $r
;;
esac
```

Comment: It just reports `RandR extension missing` here...

Comment: "Package xrandr is not available ... the following packages replace it: x11-xserver-utils:i386 x11-xserver-utils" Then `sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils` -> "x11-xserver-utils is already the newest version."

Comment: 1. try disable Xinerama
2. try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6738677&postcount=14

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but there is a gui tool that do those things you need,It's called **grandr**-*gtk interface to xrandr* and can be found in the synaptic package manager, simple one but i think it's useful (It does not work for me,Same nvidia drivers but single monitor)

Comment: Couldn't get it to work; it just reports "RandR extension missing".

Answer (score 0):

One can't rotate just one screen xrandr in a dual head  head setup with an nvidia driver.
Is my experience.

The reason seems to be that in  ordinary nvidia "twinview" both screens are actually just one screen.

Installing a more modern NVIDIA driver (302.17) allowed me to rotate a single screen. 
Once installed it can be done from within the display app in Ubuntu 12.04

there is a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170158/unable-to-change-resolution-with-beta-nvidia-driver-302-17) to the the fixing needed to be done after installing the nvidia beta driver.If you plan to use your computer in other resolutions than the screens native resolution.

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999654/linux/randr-rotation-doesn-t-work/post/5108881/#5108881

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got my 3D+compiz dualscreen with one screen rotated working on nvidia on ubuntu lucid lynx 10.04:

1) Installed Ubuntu-x-swat PPA to get nvidia-current binary driver as new as possible (and to support xrandr 1.2)
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu-x-swat

2) removed /etc/X11/xorg.conf to reset defaults

3) ran nvidia-xconfig after logout/login to generate a basic xorg.conf

4) Logout/login again, used nvidia GUI tool in system/administration to roughly place screens, saved settings to xorg.conf.

5) Identified screens from the terminal:
xrandr

6) Ran the rotate command from the terminal:
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x1024 --rotate left

7) Modified xorg.conf to have proper fine placement based on nvidia GUI-tool:
Option         "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+230, CRT: nvidia-auto-select +1400+0"

8) Made the rotation permanent by adding these lines to /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

```
# Rotate right monitor CCW
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x1024 --rotate left
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this article which does not include turning Xinerama on (Xinerama = bad from my experience!)

```
http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/05/ubuntu-enable-rotation-nvidia/
```

it needs to be adjusted for 2 screens tho. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried it; didn't work. I got one screen which I couldn't use for anything except move the mouse there.

Comment: It only works for single head setup. Not for a dual head setup