# Unable to change resolution with  beta NVIDIA driver (302.17)

Tags: nvidia

So I've installed  want to use the latest NVIDIA driver (302.17) from the [x-swats](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu-x-swat) PPA repository which was easy enough

It gives me:

- Better performance
- Ability to rotate my secondary display,
- Managing the gfx natively from the displays applet.

But, after installing it, i there are no resolution options available other than my native resolution so I cannot change the resolution in the display app or nvidia-settings.

Which is annoying when wanting to play games etc in other resolutions.

xrandr -q   ,reports no other resolutions than the native one.
The driver also seems to have scaling disabled, so games for example, running at a lower resolution aren't scaled up Meaning I get a small centered window on my screen.

According to the documentation resolutions can be added in  Xorg.conf, but I cant find any specifics on how to.

Comment: There's a reason it's the latest, unofficial, bleeding-edge, beta driver ;)

Comment: Well the current nvidia drivers are far form bleeding edge. And I cant claim that makes them work well :) Im fairly sure some xorg metamode master knows what needs to be done in xorg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself reading the xorg man pages for nvidia driver and the release notes for the new driver

Apparently it lacks support to detect what resolutions your card / monitor is capbable of because the support is being rewritten.

Adding the resolutions to your xorg.conf file manually allows games etc to swtich to the resolution they require.

to the screen section ( Section "Screen")
add the following line:

```
Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select; nvidia-auto-select {ViewPortIn=1440x900}; nvidia-auto-select {ViewPortIn=1280x1024}; nvidia-auto-select {ViewPortIn=1280x960}; nvidia-auto-select {ViewPortIn=1280x800}"
```

If you don't have a xorg.conf file, you can use nvidia-settings to create one for you then append the line stated above to it.
to get support for the specified resolutions.

In my case DFP-0 is my primary display output.
You can verify the name of your display output with the command:

```
xrandr -q
```

from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the same issue by manually installing the Nvidia version 319.49 drivers downloaded from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

following the procedure described in ["Method 4: Manual install from the official site"](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html) 
Note that I have enabled the DKMS option during install, and answered yes to the question on whether to overwrite existing xorg.conf files.

After installing, I rebooted the laptop and in nvidia-settings all resolutions were visible again.